# .NET Button Images

Tags: .net, button

In .NET, is there a namespace that has built in button images such as bulleted lists, numbered lists, bold, italic, underline etc.? Or would it be better to just create my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a class like `SystemIcons` that you are looking for, but Visual Studio does include [Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035%28VS.100%29.aspx) that has a lot of images for you to use.

For Visual Studio 2008:

> ..\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary

For Visual Studio 2010:

> ..\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary

If not there, look in your installation disk.